# Is it possible to authenticate a user through Stack Overflow API?

Tags: support, api, documentation

Is it possible to use the Stack Overflow API to authenticate a given user identity such as with Facebook, Twitter, or OpenID?

If it's possible: Can you tell me the method (s) that make this happen?

Answer (score 4):

No, not in version 1. User authentication (and the actions that go along with it, like voting and posting), might well turn up in version 2.

Comment: Can u Explain it Elaborate for this version 1 and 2 feature please, thank for advance